# Изменить метод удаления из ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

Есть класс в котором добавляю в список элементы, после чего выделяя их в чекбоксе галочкой, могу нажатием одной кнопки удалить выбранные элементы. Но мне бы хотелось вместо checkbox'a расположить кнопку delete(сделал) и по нажатию на эту кнопку удалять конкретный элемент из списка. Помогите преобразовать код пожалуйста.

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
ArrayAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    Button btnDel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDel);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, list);


    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtItem);
            list.add(edit.getText().toString());
            edit.setText("");
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

    View.OnClickListener listenerDel = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SparseBooleanArray checkedItemPositions = getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();
            int itemCount = getListView().getCount();

            for (int i = itemCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (checkedItemPositions.get(i)) {
                    adapter.remove(list.get(i));
                }
            }
            checkedItemPositions.clear();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

    btn.setOnClickListener(listener);
    btnDel.setOnClickListener(listenerDel);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

Comment: в адаптере, установите listener на кнопку, и удаляйте из адаптера элемент по позиции

Comment: btnDel.setOnClickListener(listenerDel); установил, в коде adapter вроде так удаляем по позиции  adapter.remove(list.get(i)) ? 
+ пытаюсь убрать этот чек бокс - не выходит(

Comment: не знаю, как в адаптере. Не вижу код адаптера.

Comment: вам придется делать кастомный адаптер, и переопределять у него метод getView

Comment: неужели всё так сложно? в этом же классе нельзя подобное реализовать? зачем мне данный метод?

Comment: Чтобы получить доступ к View в каждом элементе списка.